# Why message brokers don't supply total data/messages sent metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, messagebroker, apache-pulsar

My team was recently considering different message brokers to use for our project, we ended up picking Apache Pulsar, but it applies to others (Kafka). Our requirement is to track total number of messages sent and bytes sent to each subscriber for billing purposes.

I was reading documentation for metrics and was surprised to see that Pulsar doesn't track this, I've checked Kafka and the result was the same.
My understanding on this subject is minimal so is this some kind of anti-pattern? 
I understand that counter values like this never go down and for our use case - should not be reset, leading to potential (certain) overflows. But to me this could be solved by using something like a histogram in Prometheus (metrics format used in Pulsar). I am actually thinking about implementing such functionality, but am I wrong and is there a better solution for our purpose?

Comment: The producers expose bytes sent. Why should the brokers track that? They track bytes *received*

Comment: @cricket_007 it's not a historical value and is limited to the session, as far as I understand. Can't have downtime affecting accuracy of the billing :D

Comment: Then I might suggest using an external agent that tracks network traffic such as Metricbeat

Comment: Or, what's wrong with session based? If you store in Prometheus, Influx, Elastic, etc, you can aggregate there